# QGIS merging grid cells together changing resolution from 250x250m to 500x500m

Tags: qgis, merge, vector-grid, resolution, resampling

I want to change the resolution of a grid in QGIS and can't make it work. I have checked the site for similar problems but couldn't find a simple and good solution.

My Grid looks like this:
[image]

and I want to merge four cells together for the whole grid. Idealy beginning from a certain point in the city center (if that doesn't work it is okay).
[image]

in the end it should look like this for the whole grid:
[image]

if i simply create a new grid with 500x500m the orientation is not the same and the borders don't allign:

[image]

Comment: You could create a new grid with the correct resolution.

Comment: but would it have the same location as that one?

Comment: Define "location". The same extent - yes. The same orientation - possible. The same placement of grid lines - maybe.

Comment: Set the extent of the new grid to the existing grid. However, be sure to use the same CRS. See here for a similar problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/402151/88814

Comment: The screenshot you added now clearly shows that you used another CRS

Comment: yeah that was the problem. Thanks! got it!