# Dividing an irregular shaped grid pattern

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have a provincial grid used for the legal subdivision of land and need to split each grid cell into four for analysis purpose: https://github.com/matthewmeadows81/grid.

The problem lies in the properties of this grid: some of the cells are irregular and the method in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402281/168648 by @babel is the best method I've found so far, but the first step of creating a line from the centroid of each cell to the centroid of each neighboring cell just doesn't work because I suspect the irregular cell properties shown below cause issue:

[image]

Picture 1 (above): Overall grid shape.

[image]

Picture 2 (above): Top left-hand corner of grid after creating lines from centroid of each cell to the centroid of each neighboring cell.

Picture 3 (below): Top of grid where a small rectangle cell exists.
[image]

Comment: Looks like an issue of so-called "sliver polygons". Can you first remove cells below an area threshold?

Comment: You can select by area and [Eliminate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgiseliminateselectedpolygons) them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the SAGA 'Split Features Layer' tool inside a python script.  The grid was quite large and it overloaded QGIS.  My quick workaround was as follows:

1. Split each polygon grid feature apart into a separate shapefile.
2. Write a little script to iterate across the files and split each polygon as desired.

See post:
[Iterating SAGA Split Features Layer tool across files in directory using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451857/iterating-saga-split-features-layer-tool-across-files-in-directory-using-python)