Creating smaller equal sized and orientied polygons in existing grid polygons
I have a grid of large polygons that I would like to split into 16 equal sized polygons of dimension ~402.33 m x ~402.33 m (Picture 1).  The epsg is 26910. The script written does that, however, the smaller polygons are not equal and askew within the larger polygon (Picture 2).

Picture 1.

Picture 2.
The following is the sql code:
-- Drop the existing function
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS generate_grid_with_labels(geometry, integer, integer);

-- Create the updated function with the new return type
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_grid_with_labels(multipolygon_geom geometry, rows integer, cols integer)
RETURNS TABLE (geom geometry, lsd integer, concatenated_label text) AS $$
DECLARE
    x_min double precision;
    y_min double precision;
    x_max double precision;
    y_max double precision;
    width double precision;
    height double precision;
    x_step double precision;
    y_step double precision;
    x double precision;
    y double precision;
    grid_geom geometry;
    intersect_geom geometry;
    dump_record record;
BEGIN
    -- Reproject the input geometry to EPSG:26910 (UTM zone 10N)
    multipolygon_geom := ST_Transform(multipolygon_geom, 26910);

SELECT ST_XMin(multipolygon_geom), ST_YMin(multipolygon_geom), ST_XMax(multipolygon_geom), ST_YMax(multipolygon_geom)
INTO x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max;

width := x_max - x_min;
height := y_max - y_min;
x_step := width / cols;
y_step := height / rows;

FOR j IN 0..(rows-1) LOOP
    FOR i IN 0..(cols-1) LOOP
        x := x_min + (i * x_step);
        y := y_min + (j * y_step);
        grid_geom := ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[
            ST_Point(x, y),
            ST_Point(x + x_step, y),
            ST_Point(x + x_step, y + y_step),
            ST_Point(x, y + y_step),
            ST_Point(x, y)
        ])), 26910);

        -- Clip the grid cell with the input geometry
        intersect_geom := ST_Intersection(multipolygon_geom, grid_geom);

        -- Ensure the geometry is a Polygon by dumping and taking the first polygon
        FOR dump_record IN SELECT * FROM ST_Dump(intersect_geom) LOOP
            geom := dump_record.geom;
            EXIT; -- Exit after the first polygon is found
        END LOOP;

        IF (rows - j - 1) % 2 = 0 THEN
            lsd := (j * cols) + (i + 1);
        ELSE
            lsd := (j * cols) + (cols - i);
        END IF;
        
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create the table with the desired concatenated field
CREATE TABLE public.grid AS
SELECT
    prg.id,
    geoms.geom,
    prg.township_i,
    prg.range_id,
    prg.west_merid,
    prg.section_id,
    geoms.lsd,
    -- Concatenate the fields with proper padding
    LPAD(geoms.lsd::text, 2, '0') || '-' ||
    LPAD(prg.section_id::text, 2, '0') || '-' ||
    LPAD(prg.township_i::text, 3, '0') || '-' ||
    LPAD(prg.range_id::text, 2, '0') || ' W' ||
    prg.west_merid || 'M' AS label
FROM
    public.prg AS prg,
    LATERAL generate_grid_with_labels(prg.geom, 4, 4) AS geoms;

ALTER TABLE public.grid
ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(POLYGON, 26910)
USING ST_Force2D(geom);


Probably the EPSG of the initial geometry was not a projected one, so the original grid is not regular. Once you try to generate the second one inside of it the 'ST_Intersection' might deform the generated grid if the original geometry is a complex one. You could generate a regular grid (projected) in first place and then generate the second one. Also generate the smaller grid first and intersect it later

Why not use the built-in, well tested and optimized st_squaregrid()? It does exactly that: demo. select st_astext(geom) from st_squaregrid(1,st_makeenvelope(0,0,5,5))sq(geom);

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/402151/88814

As per the comment: starting from PostGIS 3.1 there's ST_SquareGrid() that does that. If I draw a large square over Vancouver and ask it to divide it into 402.33m by 402.33m squares, it does that without adding that suspicious tilt anywhere: demo at db<>fiddle
select ordinality,i,j,geom
from st_squaregrid(402.33,'polygon(( 489915.3 5456768.2
                                    ,489915.3 5497001.2
                                    ,530148.3 5497001.2
                                    ,530148.3 5456768.2
                                    ,489915.3 5456768.2
                                  ))'::geometry(Polygon,26910))
with ordinality as sq;



As to why you got that tilt in the first place, I'm betting on what @Albert immediately pointed out: the ST_Transform() whacked your input shape out of shape. You need to decide in which of the two reference systems you want the grid to look nice and perform your subdivision there.
